# Git asking for password on Gitosis from capifony

Tags: git, capistrano, gitosis, capifony

I setup a server with gitosis (yum install gitosis (CentOS 6.2)) and configure my deploy.rb as follow:

```
set :application, "uda"
set :domain,      "10.0.0.59"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/html/"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :user,        "root"
set :use_sudo,    false
#default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:port] = 22
set :php_bin, "/usr/bin/php"

set  :repository,  "gitosis@10.0.0.59:uda.git"
set :scm,         :git

set :branch,      "master"

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :update_vendors, true

set  :keep_releases,  5

# 
# ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
# set :model_manager, "doctrine"

set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
```

When I launch that with cap deploy asks for a password. Gitosis don´t have any password, so I think is asking for root password. I´m getting this:

```
==> cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote gitosis@10.0.0.59:uda.git master"
/Users/gitek/.ssh/config line 2: garbage at end of line; "#".
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/html/releases/20120126081107; true"
    servers: ["gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com"]
Password: 
    [gureak-akademi.grupogureak.com] executing command
    command finished in 58ms
Command git ls-remote gitosis@10.0.0.59:uda.git master returned status code 32768
```

Anyway, if I connect to my server via ssh and launch

```
root@centos ~]# git ls-remote gitosis@10.0.0.59:uda.git master
gitosis@10.0.0.59's password:
```

It keekps asking for a password...

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file has id_rsa.pub content